# Is it possible to get ENV variables from Azure in plain Javascript code? If yes, how?

Tags: javascript, c#, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service, websecurity

I have hard-coded the username and password from plain Javascript, which are required by an API. but I want to take them from Azure or any other sources and fed them to JS using variable/constant, so that user will not be able to see them in "sources" directly. Is it possible? if yes, please suggest me a guide/blog. If no, can you suggest alternative way? I am using c# as back-end.

Comment: Does your JavaScript run in the browser? Can you have the user enter the credentials? Either through Basic Auth or a custom solution?

Comment: Yes, we can see the javascript in sources tab. User is not entering any credentials. The credentials are passed by me to authenticate API.

Comment: You could create and host an API in Azure that reads the credentials from configuration; your javascript requests and uses them. In the end, this only obfucates but is not really more secure than having them in the sources directly without proper authentication at the API. An experienced user can also track the requests your page sends to the API in browser DevTools, so it's almost as easy as reading them from the source files. So think about whether you can change your page (or the API) to have the user enter the credentials or use an approach like OIDC/OAuth to secure your page and the API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Is it possible. You can use key-Vault.

1. Create Key-Vault in azure portal.
2. C# code for access Key-Vault value.

```cs
var KvVaule = _configuration["VaultUrl"];
 
var secretsClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(KvVaule), new DefaultAzureCredential());  

var KeyVault = secretsClient.GetSecret("VisiualStudioName");

_KeyVaultValue = KeyVault.Value.Value.ToString();
```

3. Add key-vault Url in appsetting.json

```cs
 "VaultUrl": "https://abc.vault.azure.net/"
```

4. Pass Key Vault value from c# code to JavaScripts.

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.value = _KeyVaultValue;
    return View();
}
```

KeyVault Secrets name and value.
[image]

[image]

A document by Microsoft on [Azure Key Vault secret client library for JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-node)